# Error shows if I enable html5Mode in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `$stateProvider` for routing. If I use

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

then by default error page opens. If I enable html5Mode then in error page then this error message comes. How can I resolve this ?

[image]

My route.js partial code:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function () {
        return "/404";
    });
$stateProvider
    .state('404', {
        url: "/404",
        templateUrl: "app/views/error.html"
    })
    .state('home', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "app/views/home.html"
    })
});
}]);
```

Comment: did you confiure server for html5mode?

Comment: have you add the balise `<base href="/base/">` in your index.html ?

Comment: Yeah I have added <base href="/">  in my index.html and everything is fine with this i.e. # tag is removed. But the problem is when my error page comes then this message shows(Cannot GET /error). What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you try with : $locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});

Comment: Yeah these are all same.. not working.